# where to insert IgnoreResourceNotFoundException in azure storage

Tags: asp.net, azure, storage

hi im trying to program a query to select data by employee id, but when there are no entries in the table, i get a error. i understand i can use IgnoreResourceNotFoundException=true, but i do not know where to insert this code. hope you guys can help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace MessageBoard_Data
{
public class MessageBoardDataSource
{


private const string messageTableName = "MessageTable";
private const string connectionStringName = "DataConnectionString";
private static CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
private CloudTableClient tableClient;
private const string messageImageBlobName = "golfermessageboardpics";
private CloudBlobClient blobClient;
private CloudBlobContainer blobContainer;
private const string messageQueueName = "golfermessageboardqueue"; 
private CloudQueueClient queueClient;
private CloudQueue queue;


public MessageBoardDataSource()
{
string connectionString = RoleEnvironment.
GetConfigurationSettingValue(connectionStringName);

storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

tableClient = new CloudTableClient(storageAccount.TableEndpoint.
AbsoluteUri,storageAccount.Credentials);

tableClient.RetryPolicy = RetryPolicies.Retry(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
tableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(messageTableName);



blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(messageImageBlobName);
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist();


var permissions = blobContainer.GetPermissions();
permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
blobContainer.SetPermissions(permissions);
queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(messageQueueName);
queue.CreateIfNotExist();


}
public IEnumerable<MessageBoardEntry> GetEntriesbyid(string EmployeeID)
{
TableServiceContext tableServiceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
tableServiceContext.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;
tableServiceContext.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true;
var results = from h in   tableServiceContext.CreateQuery
<MessageBoardEntry>(messageTableName)
where h.EmployeeID == EmployeeID
select h;
return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var context = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
context.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;
```

Then query the context as you intend and it will return null if not found from then on when you query the context.

**Update:**
If this is a newly created table you may be running into a known issue with the development Storage Emulator.

You may need to add a dummy item into your table before using it for the first time to ensure that it knows what the schema is. So try the steps in the following post: http://deeperdesign.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/azure-table-storage-what-a-pain-in-the-ass/

Comment: hi, i tried your method but it still doesnt work....i added the code to my question, please tell me what went wrong... thanks a million!!!

Comment: You want me to guess what went wrong? I don't know what went wrong. What error message did you get? What unexpected behaviour happened? As far as I can see you are missing an angle bracket after CreateQuery and you have commented out that key line for IgnoreResourceNotFoundException

Comment: sorry to trouble you, but i got this error "Server Error in '/' Application." "One of the request inputs is not valid" i did un-comment the 2 lines, but this error still props out.... thanks again.... i edited the angle bracket too.

Comment: thanks, in the end i add just add a dummy entry. though it doesnt look good, but im out of time.... thanks again.